# What does a taxi driver say to the customer when he gets to the required destination?

Tags: phrase-request, politeness

I am making a conversation when using public transport in English. And I don't know what a taxi driver might say to inform his customer that he has already got to the required destination. Is it "here we are?"

Comment: In most major American cities, most taxi drivers are not native speakers of English.

Comment: That's a very valid point. @Jasper

Comment: "we have reached the destination"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he could use sentences like:
1. "Here we are"
2. "We've reached"
3. "This is it"
4. "Destination arrived"
There are many more sentences he could use. There are many phrases (and slang phrases) that he can use too. Please note that various places have various slang associated with it. There are numerous ways he could let you know. But the most commonly used sentences are given above.

Comment: +1 for 1,2 and 5 as I hear that in most of the cases - India and abroad. -1 for '3' as it looks strange to me. It appears that both of them were on some mission! '4' shows that the driver had nothing more to offer! :)

Comment: I've heard many taxi drivers use "This is it" in Hollywood movies. So clearly, this is widely used in the US.

Comment: #3 sounds like they were in a sci-fi film with aliens chasing them and still they made it.  5 is the best.

Comment: @VarunKN and iif you heard something in a Hollywood movie, that does not mean it is widely used. As jasper commented, majority of cab drivers are not NS.

Comment: I beg to differ. I still think it is widely used as a slang by taxi drivers. But let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: I've edited out "we made it". I agree it sounds like a movie dialog.